# show text and image in browser using php script

Tags: php

I create php script that shows the Id and the image stored in mysql database, but i can just see the image without the Id, how can i show the image and the id in this php script ?

```html
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT image,image_type FROM images where id = $id";

$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));;
  
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($r);
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
$ss=$result['image_type'];

if ($ss == 'php') {
   echo 'Type of image ' . $result['image_type'];
            echo ( $result['image']);
} else if ($ss == 'android') {
   echo 'Type of image ' . $result['image_type'];
            echo base64_decode( $result['image'] );
        }
  
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

this is what i get when i execute script :

[image]

note : when i remove **echo 'Type of image ' . $result['image_type'];** from the code the image is properly displayed. but i want to show the image and its type too.

Comment: Show actual, and expected results.

Comment: Updated my post its clear now i think

Comment: So is $ss php or android?

Comment: You cant show an image and text at the same time. If you want text in an image try looking at the GD library. If you want the text separate from an image try loading the image and the text apart from each other

Comment: i want the text separate from an image how to do it ?

Comment: I think you need img tag around the base64 string.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: but i want to use the result of the image and its id in an android apps, so android cannot getinput stream of URL if i use img tag

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. If you look at the link to jsfiddle in the link above you see how there is both text and a red dot. The red dot is a base64 img.